# WHERE var = "$name" AND var = "$name"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select stories for my mysql database Where the author variable is equal to a list of names.

I basically have a list of names that I want use in determining what stories to pull.

```
 $names = "name1 name2 name3 name4"

 $get_stories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM glnce_stories WHERE author = '$names'  ORDER BY id DESC");
```

I know that this isn't the right way to do but I was looking for some solutions on how I might be able to break that list up so I can have it pull from the authors in that `$names` variable.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for that if you want to be lazy. You will just have to turn your names list into a comma-separated string:

```
$names = "name1,name2,name3,name4";
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE FIND_IN_SET(author, '$names')"
```

That's maybe easier than a list of `OR` conditions or preparing a proper string list for an `IN` clause. (You can _real_escape_string the whole comma separated list, instead of each name.)

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't able to change the format of the `$names` variable, this should work:

```
$names = 'name1 name2 name3 name4';
$names = '"' . implode('","', explode(' ', $names)) . '"';

$get_stories = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM glnce_stories WHERE author IN(' . $names . ') ORDER BY id DESC');
```

Comment: Do you really think `implode( explode )` is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: No, but as I pointed out. If he wouldn't be able to change the format of the `$names` variable this would probably be the easiest way. The preferred way is of course to do like in @mario's answer.

Answer (score 2):

comma separate the names and then 
use "WHERE author in (" . $names . ")";

Comment: Maybe provide an example on how to turn the $names string into comma separated parts using explode/implode too..

Comment: That will find where the author is any single name in the list.  So this is effectively `where author='name1' OR author='name2' OR ...`.  That's probably what he wants, but he did specify AND.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense though.  How could author be "Jim,John,Fred,Phil"?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WHERE field in (list)` like this:

```
$names = "'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'";
$get_stories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM glnce_stories WHERE author in ($names)  ORDER BY id DESC");
```

So, your query should look something like this: `SELECT * FROM glnce_stories WHERE author in ('Bob', 'Steve', 'Andrey', 'Mike', 'Jenna')`

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
$names = "name1 name2 name3 name4";
$names = "'".implode ("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', explode(' ', $names))."'";
$get_stories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM glnce_stories WHERE author in ($names)");
```